# Use the content of a cell as function input Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the content of a cell to be the input of a function, in particoular this i the complete function is this:

`=query({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vkfz7i8vMRY96fnwiP9oGdChqE9SSxccb_uECen4cp0/", "202012!B5:AA");IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vkfz7i8vMRY96fnwiP9oGdChqE9SSxccb_uECen4cp0/", "202101!B5:AA")},"Select * where Col1 is not null ")`

What i would like to do is to store part of the function in a cell (which will be automatically created through some automations):

`{IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vkfz7i8vMRY96fnwiP9oGdChqE9SSxccb_uECen4cp0/", "202012!B5:AA");IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vkfz7i8vMRY96fnwiP9oGdChqE9SSxccb_uECen4cp0/", "202101!B5:AA")}`

So that I can call the function in something like:

`=query(A1,"Select * where Col1 is not null ")`

Yet I still didn't figure out how to pass the cell A1 so that it would be considered as part of the function by GS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [named function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534) to save your whole importrange formula and use it as shown in the screenshot

[image]