# Create an array of combined tab data by generating sequential tab names

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with many tabs, each named based on the year of data it contains. I'd like to collect all of the data into a single array so that I can run a `QUERY` against it. I'm currently able to do this like so:

```
=QUERY({'2018'!A:O;'2019'!A:O;'2020'!A:O;'2021'!A:O;'2022'!A:O;'2023'!A:O}, "")
```

However, I have several different queries I'm performing on this data and I don't want to have to update each of them every time there's a new year of data in the spreadsheet. I'm looking for a way to automatically generate the list of tab names. I was hoping to do something like this:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 2018 |
| 3 | `=CONCAT(JOIN("!A:O;", SEQUENCE(1, A1, A2, 1)), "!A:O")` |
| 4 | `=QUERY({INDIRECT(A3)}, "")` |

This would allow me to simply increment the value in `A1` whenever I add another year of data to this spreadsheet in a new tab. But it seems `INDIRECT` can't handle multiple cell ranges at once, resulting in the following error on `A4`:

```
Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is '2018!A:O;2019!A:O;2020!A:O;2021!A:O;2022!A:O;2023!A:O'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.
```

I also tried using `MAP` to apply the `INDIRECT` to one range at a time:

```
={MAP(SEQUENCE(1, A1, A2, 1), LAMBDA(tab, INDIRECT(CONCAT(tab, "!A:O"))))}
```

But the ranges are unable to combine and I get this error:

```
Result should be a single column.
```

Comment: You can also create a `custom function` to relay the saved array [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75748351/5479575)

Comment: `REDUCE()` with `VSTACK()` will do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REDUCE()` with `VSTACK()` may work because `REDUCE()` has capability to store processed result to accumulator and then spill output both horizontally and vertically.

```
=QUERY(REDUCE(,TOCOL(SEQUENCE(1,A1,A2,1)),
LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,QUERY(INDIRECT(x&"!A:B"),"where A is not null")))),"offset 1")
```

[image]

Comment: The `TOCOL` seems to be unnecessary, and I was able to replace the inner `QUERY(..., "where A is not null")` with `IFERROR(..., "")` to make it a bit cleaner. I turned it into a `custom function` and it works great. Thanks so much!